# Using np.nan() to find average of each row and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 10 columns with GDP between 2006 and 2015 of 15 different countries. I am trying to get the mean GDP from the last ten years. For example, Germany's average GDP from 2006 to 2015. This is the code I tried to use:

```
avgGDP = pd.DataFrame(Top15,columns=['2006','2007','2008','2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'])
avgGDP['avg10'] = np.nanmean(avgGDP)
```

However, I get the same mean value for each country i.e. Germany 1,000,000; Spain 1,000,000; UK 1,000,000 etc.

Any thoughts on how to get individual mean for each country?

EDITED:

Here's a screenshot of Top15:

[image]

Comment: It's helpful if you could provide a sample of `Top15` to make it easier to reproduce the problem and write concrete answers. Thanks.

Comment: Just done it. Sorry!

Comment: That helps but it's best as text so that people don't need to retype it all in to help you and [many other reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just filter the null values and then run a mean method?

```
df = (avgGDP.dropna( inplace = True )).mean()
```

It seems to me you are running a mean on the entire dataframe to get an array and then trying to make that array into a column. The better approach could also be to transpose the data frame and insert as a column:

```
avgGDP = avgGDP.T
avgGDP['newRow'] = np.nanmean(avgGDP)
avgGDP.T
```

Comment: Hi Colton, when I run that code, it still gives me the same mean for each row :(

Comment: Can you run `df.tail(15).T.tail(5).to_dict()` and post it below?

Comment: Got it. Inspired by your answer I used T to get the mean. Here's the code for future readers:

avgGDP['avg'] = avgGDP.T.mean()